# Why did my eggless cup cake prepared with condensed milk get charred in a convection microwave?

Tags: milk, microwave, cupcakes

We have prepared the eggless cupcake with condensed milk. We have used convection mode in microwave.
Preheated to 200C and then baked the cake for 10 mins. It started off nicely, but at 10th min, we got the charred cake.
What could be the problem with this?

Comment: Could you possibly post the exact recipe that you are using? I've never seen a cupcake recipe with condensed milk before.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to make this cake in an actual oven (even if the recipe specified a microwave oven) as the heat will be more even. Anyway, ovens can be remarkably inaccurate in temperature so perhaps although you set your oven at 200 C it may have been actually at 225 C say. The batter may have also been quite thick and so have a higher tendency to burn unlike a thinner, wetter batter, if you pair this with the inaccuracy of the oven temperature then it's not surprising that it burnt.

Hope this helps for next time!

Comment: @Sebiddyhef, Thanks for the nice answer. I will try this and let u know the result in due course. I will try these possibilities. 1. Reduce the temp to 175C and thinner batter. 2. 200C and thinner batter. What i have observed in the previous case, is it has raised  as expected and came down in seconds. May be stuff was not sufficient??

Comment: Perhaps you could just try a different recipe if all else fails, there are plenty of other eggless cakes using condensed milk as a quick google search: (http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eggless+condensed+milk+cake) reveals.

Answer (score 0):

I have been making black forest cakes in the microwave for over 6 years without any errors.

The time you used was way too long! For 600g it takes a maximum of 8 mins and 30 seconds to bake.

I make walnut and banana muffins based on which, I am giving you the following advice,

Next time make sure:

1. The batter flows slightly but is not too liquid;
2. Set your oven on combination mode if you can, or convection mode is fine;
3. Temperature 600ºC and time: first 2 mins, then a 30 second wait followed by another minute;
4. Test with a clean needle or toothpick after a minute of it cooling inside the oven.

Comment: I suggest you mistyped the temperature on step three.